# I want a match if there are more than 5 email addresses in the string: @ or .com appears more than 5 times

Tags: regex

I want a match if the string contains more than 5 email IDs, I am new to regex and tried the min max function but no use

treasurymiddleoffice@acme.com;henryf@acme.com;sayeds@acme.com;mihirs@acme.com;ankurg@acme.com;supriyakumars@acme.com;manojp@acme.com;structuring@acme.com;balai@acme.com;christopherh@acme.com;samratn@acme.com;shubhip@acme.com;georgeo@acme.com;sheemainz@acme.com;sakinaab@acme.com

Comment: Which language or environment are you using this in?

Comment: Why don't you just count the `@`s?

Comment: Plenty of e-mail addresses don't contain ".com", and plenty of strings that aren't e-mail addresses (e.g., URLs) do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the the format of your email addresses matches your example, you could try this pattern:

```
(.+?@[\w-]+\.\w+;?){6,}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex:

```
^(?=(.*@){6,})
```

It asserts there are at least 6 (which "more than 5") `@` symbols.